# How do I change the colour of an image in Pygame without changing its transparency?

Tags: python, pygame

It sounds like a simple thing to do , but I'm struggling.
I have a png image of a rectangle with a transparent centre called "zero". I want to change the colour of the visible part of the image. To try and change it, I have tried using "zero.fill" but no option I try changes only the non-transparent part, or it merges the new colour with the old and stays like that.
I'm not keen on installing numpy as I wish to take the finished program to a friend who doesn't have it. Any simple suggestions welcome.

Comment: place the image over a rectangle of equal size with required color ..

Comment: I tried that but either the transparency doesn't work or it goes through to the black background beneath the coloured rectangular image.

Comment: do you need to be able to change the color in the code? If not you could create the other image with any image software and alternate between them in the code based on some condition

Comment: I stripped it back and rebuilt it as per Ankur's reversal suggestion and it worked. I still don't know why it worked 2nd time round but not the first? As far as I can tell, both codes were the same?

Comment: strange indeed, you code post before and after. I am curious now

Comment: You should really post your code in order to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got an example that works with per pixel alpha surfaces that can also be translucent. The `fill` function just loops over the surface's pixels and sets them to the new color, but keeps their alpha value. It's probably not recommendable to do this every frame with many surfaces. (Press f, g, h to change the color.)

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def fill(surface, color):
    """Fill all pixels of the surface with color, preserve transparency."""
    w, h = surface.get_size()
    r, g, b, _ = color
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            a = surface.get_at((x, y))[3]
            surface.set_at((x, y), pg.Color(r, g, b, a))


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    # Uncomment this for a non-translucent surface.
    # surface = pg.Surface((100, 150), pg.SRCALPHA)
    # pg.draw.circle(surface, pg.Color(40, 240, 120), (50, 50), 50)
    surface = pg.image.load('bullet2.png').convert_alpha()
    surface = pg.transform.rotozoom(surface, 0, 2)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_f:
                    fill(surface, pg.Color(240, 200, 40))
                if event.key == pg.K_g:
                    fill(surface, pg.Color(250, 10, 40))
                if event.key == pg.K_h:
                    fill(surface, pg.Color(40, 240, 120))

        screen.fill(pg.Color('lightskyblue4'))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, pg.Color(40, 50, 50), (210, 210, 50, 90))
        screen.blit(surface, (200, 200))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

[image: bullet2.png]

Comment: I've added a translucent image to my answer, so that you can better see the effect. Only the color is changed, but the transparency stays the same.

Comment: Thanks skrx, this will be more useful for complex or themed images.

Comment: It wasn't long before I needed skrx's method. It's much more flexible. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this version, the visible and transparent parts are the other way round to the original question as per Ankur's suggestion.
Here is the essential working code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

def load_image(name):
    image = pygame.image.load(name).convert()
    return image

def resize(obj, w, h):
    global scale
    return pygame.transform.scale(obj, (int(w * scale), int(h * scale)))


pink = (255, 0, 160)
red = (255, 0, 0)
peach = (255, 118, 95)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
blue_1 = (38, 0, 160)
dark_yellow = (255, 174, 0)
green = (38, 137, 0)
orange = (255, 81, 0)
colour = [pink, red, peach, blue, blue_1, dark_yellow, green, orange, green]
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
scale = 4
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((292 * scale, 240 * scale),0, 32)
banner = load_image("banner.png") #292x35
zero = load_image("zero.png") #5x7
c = 0
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    rgb = colour[c]
    c = c + 1
    if c > 7:
        c = 0
    pygame.draw.line(banner, rgb, (53, 21), (53, 27), 5) #line the same size as zero image
    banner.blit(zero, (51, 21)) #blit image with transparency over line
    large_banner = resize(banner, 292, 35)
    screen.blit(large_banner, (0, 0))
    clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Ah okay, that just changes the color of the subjacent rect (or line in this case) and then blits the image with transparency above. It's good that this works for you, but this actually doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code for drop all color brightness

```
    def drop(surface):
        w, h = surface.get_size()
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                r = surface.get_at((x, y))[0]
                if r>150:
                   r-=50
                g = surface.get_at((x, y))[1]
                if g>150:
                   g-=50
                b = surface.get_at((x, y))[2]
                if b>150:
                   b-=50
                a = surface.get_at((x, y))[3]
                surface.set_at((x, y), pygame.Color(r, g, b, a)) 

    img = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert_alpha()
    drop(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem a little bit differently than others appear to, but I was trying to figure this out and the answers listed here did not give me exactly what I was looking for. I've slowly built off of what I've found to to accomplish my goals.

Firstly, I just wanted to change the colour of my animation frames to a random colour chosen from a list. The method I discovered used pygame.PixelAray() and .replace() to swap one colour for another:

```
self.fire_frame_list = glob.glob("pictures\\Boom_Pow\\Colour_Flame\\*.png")
self.fire_frame_list.sort()
self.fire_frame_anim = [pygame.PixelArray(pygame.image.load(path)) for path in self.fire_frame_list]
...
self.fire_img = self.fire_frame_anim[self.frame_index]
self.fire_img.replace(self.colour, self.new_colour)
...
self.colour = self.new_colour
self.new_colour = randRGB()
```

In this code I gather the paths of my animation frames, sort them, and then load and convert the images into PixelArays. I seclect my current image using a variable called frame_index, and then change the colour for that frame. However, when I decided to change the colour midway through the animation, I encountered a problem; the second half of my animation - the frames that came after I had changed the desired colour - were their original colour - white.

In order to remedy this, I had to ensure that all the animation frames had their colour changed upon creation.

```
self.fire_frame_list = glob.glob("pictures\\Boom_Pow\\Colour_Flame\\*.png")
self.fire_frame_list.sort()
self.fire_frame_anim = [pygame.PixelArray(pygame.image.load(path)) for path in self.fire_frame_list]
for img in self.fire_frame_anim:
    img.replace((255,255,255), self.new_colour)
```

For a while this worked perfectly, until I tried using this code with a translucent image. I made sure to use .convert_alpha() on my image so as to keep my base colour as white and have the alpha value be the changed value. This worked, but not with my PixelArrays.

Although printing a list of my pixels with each RGBA value listed showed the correct values, .replace() only changed the colour of the pixels with full opacity, leaving the rest white. After much experimenting, I realized I needed to create a list of my pizel alpha values using the same method I had used to check that .convert_alpha() had given me the values I wanted.

```
self.img = pygame.image.load("pictures\\Boom_Pow\\Bubbloid.png").convert_alpha()
self.pix = {self.img.get_at((i, j))[3] for j in range(10) for i in range(10)}
self.img = pygame.PixelArray(self.img)

for a in self.pix:
    self.img.replace((255, 255, 255, a), self.colour + (a,))
```

To start, I loaded my image and converted it to its alpha values. Next, I created a dictionary where each key was a possible pixel alpha value - the [3] is the index number for the alpha values in the colour list. Using dictionary keys ensured that I would not have any duplicate items. I then converted my images into PixelArrays and ran a loop that changed the colour for each of my possible alpha values.

This has been working the way that I wish, however I believe it is important to state that I only had 4 levels of transparency, and I do not know how python would handle having to run through tens or even hundreds of levels of transparency. However, this method works for the simple images I have created, and I hope I was able to help someone else as well.
[Many of my little bubbles, filled with a random colour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1A35.png)
[My lantern, colour change midway through animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTuIa.gif)

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than all these answers make it out to be.

If you read the [Surface.fill documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) it says that you can use `special_flags` to change the blend mode. This has been the case since pygame 1.8 which released in 2008.

Here's a little graphic I got from [Open Game Art](https://opengameart.org/content/dungeon-crawl-32x32-tiles-supplemental):

[image: Original monster image]

If you play around with the different `special_flags`, you can create different effects. The MIN function is probably what you want. Especially if your base image is white/ brightly coloured:

```
def some_loading_function() -> pygame.Surface:
    # just pretend that we're loading an image here

graphic = some_loading_function().convert_alpha()
red = (255, 0, 0, 255)
graphic.fill(red, special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

[image: Monster with red overlay applied]

The MIN function compares the fill colour to the original pixel colour and keeps whatever value is the smallest for each channel. Using the example above:

- Red is always the maximum so the original value is chosen
- Blue is always the minimum so the original value is discarded
- Green is always the minimum so the original value is discarded
- Alpha is always the maximum so the original value is chosen

If you want to set the entire visible area to the same colour then first replace every visible pixel with white using the MAX function (which is basically the opposite of MIN), then fill with the colour you want using MIN:

```
graphic.fill((255, 255, 255, 0), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
graphic.fill((0, 200, 100, 255), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MIN)
```

[image: Monster texture replaced with a block colour]